# How to extract relevant text between two lines using regex

Tags: regex, r, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

```
Berat: 0.25kg
Rp 115.000
Jumlah:
Beli
Ke Dafta
```

Here I want to extract Rp 115.00 and note that weights 0.25 kg are variable

I am trying

`\b.*\n\K.*(?=\n*\n)`

but its giving me "Rp 115.00" and "Jumlah:"
There are multiple entries of Rp for eg Rp 10 ,Rp 400 in the text but I only want to extract the one between "Berat" and "Jumlah" . And these numbers are also variable
PS- I am looking for solutions with regex

Comment: The distinction between relevant and irrelevant text is not yet clear. What is the underlying rule you are using to match the text?

Comment: I only want to extract Rp 115.000

Comment: If these are lines and not a single string `v1 <- readLines('file.txt');grep('^[A-Za-z]+\\s+[0-9.]+', v1, value=TRUE)#
[1] "Rp 115.000"`

Comment: `^Rp\s.*$` with the multi-line option on matches `Rp 115.000`, but depends on it being on a line of it's own.

Comment: 115 is also variable

Comment: Based on @stribizhev 's answer, if you want specifically the Rp that is in after Berat and before Jumlah, you can try `gsub("(?s).*Berat[^\n]*\n(Rp\\s+\\d+\\.*\\d+)\nJumlah.*", "\\1", s, perl=T)`. This assumes there are no spaces before Rp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

> I only want to extract Rp 115.000

You can use a `gsub` with the `(?s).*(Rp\\s+\\d+\\.\\d+).*` regex to extract it from the text:

```
gsub("(?s).*(Rp\\s+\\d+\\.\\d+).*", "\\1", s, perl=T)
##[1] "Rp 115.000"
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/H0MoK9)

The `.*` will match any symbols (even a newline due to `(?s)` modifier) and `Rp\\s+\\d+\\.\\d+` will match the pattern *Rp* + *whitespace* + *number* + *.* + *number*.